# Is there a mechanism to trigger a Python script to update the google spreadsheet?

Tags: python, gspread

I am using `gspread` library in Python to write the data to a google spreadsheet. The data which is being written in the spreadsheet changes every day. So, my question is that is there a way to set some kind of trigger on the Google Spreadsheet which can call Python script to get the new data and update the spreadsheet every day.

Comment: Not that I know of. But I read a column of a spreadsheet every 2 seconds every day, never hit the free API limits. You could use a cell to trigger an update

Comment: Sorry.. but why not trigger the Python script to write to GSheet instead of triggering the GSheet to fetch the data?

Comment: I solved the problem by creating a time-based trigger in Google App Script to call a Flask-based API that fetches the latest data and populates the spreadsheet.